# Saving data iphone

Tags: cocoa

In my app people can read newsmessages and add a reaction etcetra. The articels are loaded from JSON/XML into a UITableview.

I want to make a new UITableviewController that's called 'favorites' the idea is to put under each article an button to save the message into their 'favorites' in the app.

Does anyone know how to do that? I just need some tips! Do i need to save data in a .plist or do i need to use userdefaults?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do it either way.

For me, plist saving/loading is at most times easier, but that's just a matter of taste :

```
NSMutableArray* favorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filename];
```